# How doesn't add null value to Guava's LoadingCache?

Tags: java, xml, caching, xpath, guava

I have to use Guava's `LoadingCache` for caching xpath expression to xpath values.

The trouble is that not all xpaths have values. Most of the time the value is `null`.

Code snippet:

```
private LoadingCache<String, List<String>> cachedXpaths = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .maximumSize(1000)
        .concurrencyLevel(5)
        .weakKeys()
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, List<String>>() {
            @Override
            public List<String> load(String key) throws Exception {
                return createListByKey(key);
            }
        });

private static List<String> createListByKey(String key) throws Exception {
    List<String> values = null;
    try {
        values = instance.getXpathValues(key);
    } catch (XPathExpressionException ignore) {
    }
    return values;
}
```

Result:

```
testEncounterSection(com.epam.cdatest.section.EncountersSectionTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 sec  <<< FAILURE!
com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: com.epam.cdatest.exceptions.XpathHasEmptyValueException
    at com.epam.cdatest.parsers.XpathEvaluator.getXpathValues(XpathEvaluator.java:123)
    at com.epam.cdatest.parsers.XpathEvaluator.createListByKey(XpathEvaluator.java:53)
    at com.epam.cdatest.parsers.XpathEvaluator.access$000(XpathEvaluator.java:32)
    at com.epam.cdatest.parsers.XpathEvaluator$1.load(XpathEvaluator.java:46)
    at com.epam.cdatest.parsers.XpathEvaluator$1.load(XpathEvaluator.java:43)
```

How to avoid calling `load()` when xpath value is empty?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the call to `load()` instead of just returning an empty list? In fact, the cache can't know which keys are not allowed and thus will try to load at least once. The loader would then have to decide what to do with the keys.

Comment: @Thomas how does skip this empty list return? or how does tune cache for removing empty lists firstly?

Comment: It doesn't skip the `return values` call but after that the cache would not load the value for that given key anymore and would always return that empty list, which indicates that there are no xpath values for that key.

Comment: Unless you really really need to differentiate between "illegal" and "nothing there", I'd suggest to return an empty list in both cases.

Comment: @maaartinus I am wondering to know efficiency of this cache if values for List<String> is empty. Does this cache remove it farther compare to list which has some values? Can you explain more about this?

Comment: @nazar_art It'd handle it exactly the same way as other values, which may or may not be what you want. But I guess, it is the right thing, as illegal paths probably need about the same processing time as legal ones (measure it if you really care).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to differentiate between an empty `List<String>` and a null one, since `LoadingCache` doesn't support nulls, you can use a `LoadingCache<String, Optional<List<String>>>`:

```
private LoadingCache<String, Optional<List<String>>> cachedXpaths = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
        .expireAfterWrite(3, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
        .maximumSize(1000)
        .concurrencyLevel(5)
        .weakKeys()
        .build(new CacheLoader<String, Optional<List<String>>>() {
            @Override
            public Optional<List<String>> load(String key) {
                try {
                    // If getXpathValues() can also return null, use fromNullable()
                    return Optional.of(instance.getXpathValues(key));
                } catch (XPathExpressionException | XpathHasEmptyValueException ignore) {
                    // Maybe log something here as well
                    return Optional.absent();
                }
            }
        });
```

---

Update: if you're not familiar with `Optional`, there's the [Javadoc](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html?com/google/common/base/Optional.html), a page in the [Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/UsingAndAvoidingNullExplained#Optional), as well as all the documentation for Java 8 which now includes an equivalent class.

TL;DR it's a wrapper which can be tested for the presence of its content:

```
Optional<List<String>> optionalXpaths = cachedXpaths.getUnchecked(str);
if (optionalXpaths.isPresent()) {
    List<String> xpaths = optionalXpaths.get();
    // Do something with xpaths
}
```

or alternatively (but it's uglier):

```
List<String> xpaths = cachedXpaths.getUnchecked(str).orNull();
if (xpaths != null) {
    // Do something with xpaths
}
```